# Import of same file using compass / sass / scss does not get included

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have this scss file:

test.scss

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)  {
  @import 'desktop_vars';
  @import 'global_dynamic';
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)  {
  @import 'smartphone_vars';
  @import 'global_dynamic';
}
```

global_dynamic.scss

```
#companies {
  margin: 0px $envelope-Margin-Right 0 $envelope-Margin-Left;
}

#envelope {
  padding: 0 $envelope-Margin-Right 0 $envelope-Margin-Left;
}

#footer {
  margin: 0 $envelope-Margin-Right 0 $envelope-Margin-Left;
}
```

smartphone_vars.scss

```
$envelope-Margin-Left: 5px;
$envelope-Margin-Right: 7px;
```

desktop_vars.scss

```
$envelope-Margin-Left: 25px;
$envelope-Margin-Right: 47px;
```

resulting test.css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* line 1, ../../resources/assets/sass/global_dynamic.scss */
  #companies {
    margin: 0px 45px 0 25px;
  }

  /* line 5, ../../resources/assets/sass/global_dynamic.scss */
  #envelope {
    padding: 0 45px 0 25px;
  }

  /* line 9, ../../resources/assets/sass/global_dynamic.scss */
  #footer {
    margin: 0 45px 0 25px;
  }
}
```

if i change the order in test.scss of the imports, that is, first smartphone, then desktop, the resulting css file looks like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* line 1, ../../resources/assets/sass/global_dynamic.scss */
  #companies {
    margin: 0px 7px 0 5px;
  }

  /* line 5, ../../resources/assets/sass/global_dynamic.scss */
  #envelope {
    padding: 0 7px 0 5px;
  }

  /* line 9, ../../resources/assets/sass/global_dynamic.scss */
  #footer {
    margin: 0 7px 0 5px;
  }
}
```

so: the second import of global_dynamic never works

why?

Answer (score 0):

in config.rb

remove this line:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
```

or comment it out like this

```
#require 'compass/import-once/activate'
```

so annoying